# How to show that we reach $1$ at an odd or even turn without brute force

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

Consider the following challenge between two players A and B. They are given the initial terms $a_0= 3^{2014}$ and $b_0= 15^{4028}$ of two sequences, and the scope is to reach $1$ before the other, and this can be done dividing the preceding term by a prime divisor **or** taking the square root of it if it is a perfect square (e.g. from $81$ one can get  to $27$ but also to $9$) .
If the two players are **optimal** and do one of the operations once each, how to prove that if A is the first to play, then A will win out of $a_n$  and B will out of $b_n$?

What confuses me is the optimality of the players. I have guessed that it means both of them leave an even number to the opponent, in view of, e.g., $3^2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 1.$ With this constraint, indeed A won out of $a_n$. However I (hopefully) must be missing something.

Comment: Maybe I am misreading.  Isn't it clear that the optimal strategy is to take square roots whenever you can (so whenever $ord_p(a_n)$ is even for all primes $p$, and when you can't take out (at most) one of each prime factor p until all the orders are even again?

Comment: So, are you saying that an optimal player B will win upon going first, even if A is also optimal?  That sounds as if there is a single optimal path for A and another for B and these paths are of equal length...

Comment: @abiessu I have to be misreading.  The way I understood the game (probably incorrectly), each player takes turns trying to reduce their own number.  I don't see where A ever considers what B is doing.  In this particular example, A has a much shorter path than B...so whoever goes first, A wins.  But, I am increasingly convinced I am looking at the wrong game.

Comment: Ah!  They are both working on the same number.  Got it.  From all the A's and B's I thought A was working on $a_n$ and B was working on $b_n$.  Never mind.

Comment: @lulu Yes, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the numbers will always be $3^k$, starting with $3^{2014}$.  $A$ can ensure a victory by always diving the given number by 3.  That way $B$ will always get a number of the form $3^{2k+1}$, which is not a square, and will have to return a $3^{2k}$.  Repeat until $A$ gets 81.  Then square root to pass a 9 to $B$, get a 3 in return, and claim a win.

In the second case, the number is $3^k5^k$, so $A$ does have an option.  If he square roots, $B$ should do the same, and then we have $3^{1007}5^{1007}$.  Then (or otherwise), $A$ will return a number $3^k 5^l$, where $k, l$ have different parity.  $B$ then removes a factor from the even exponent, and $A$ will always have a number of the form $3^{2a+1}5^{2b+1}$, until eventually one of the factors is finished, and $B$ gets to start in a situation of a prime to an even power, which was the first case of the problem.

Comment: A and B work on the same number. They won't agree on what to do, as you suggest. And anyway, in your first case scenario B wins.

Comment: Thanks, edited the terminating condition on the first case.  If $A$ plays as described, $B$ will have no choice at all in any of his moves.

Comment: You know, I do thank you for your effort, as your $a_n$'s A is certainly the best. However I was particularly concerned with this optimality thing in $b_n$: how do you know taking the square root at the beginning is the ideal move for A? Rather, since it turned into a defeat you should definitely show that doing otherwise wouldn't have been better. But that would definitely be brute force...   My bet? The problem is likely ill-posed.